# How can I curl a server that is running in a Docker container from my host machine?

Tags: node.js, docker, curl, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a Node.js server running on port 8080 inside of a Docker container. I am able to `curl` the server with `curl http://localhost:8080` from a shell inside of the container without trouble, but I am unable to `curl` the server from my host machine even though I have mapped the ports.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:19.7

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "npm", "run", "start:dev" ]
```

Here is mydocker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  app:
    container_name: app
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/app/
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules

  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:15.2
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:6.20
    environment:
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=admin@admin.com
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=admin
      - PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT=5050
    ports:
      - "5050:5050"

volumes:
  data:
```

I have tried `curl http://localhost:8080` from a terminal on my host machine and was expecting to see a response but instead receive `curl: (52) Empty reply from server`. I have also tried `curl http://127.0.0.1:8080` and `curl http://app:8080` and received the same error.

Comment: What code is actually running in the `app` container; is it listening on 0.0.0.0:8080 (not the container-private localhost but all interfaces, and on the second ports number)?  The `volumes:` overwrite the image code with something from the host and then the library tree with an anonymous volume, is this causing you to run unexpected code?

Comment: @DavidMaze I'm using Fastify to run the server, and it was listening on the container-private localhost. Initially I was listening with `fastify.listen({ port: 8080 })` but after reading your comment I'm listening with `fastify.listen({ port: 8080, host: "0.0.0.0"  })` and it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to David's comment I've figured it out. I was listening with `fastify.listen({ port: 8080 })` but now I'm listening with `fastify.listen({ port: 8080, host: "0.0.0.0" })` and it works. This is also in the Fastify docs and I just missed it.